# Oracle JDBC Datasource - ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Tags: sql, oracle, jdbc, datasource

I have a small java console application that creates a raw jdbc connection as follows and returns it

```
public static Connection createConnection(Properties props) {
    Connection conn = null;
    {
      try
      {
        Class.forName(props.getProperty("jdbcClass"));
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
            props.getProperty("jdbcUrl"),
            props.getProperty("username"),
            props.getProperty("password")
            );
        return conn;
      }
      catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
      {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
      catch (SQLException e)
      {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
    return null;
}
```

With a properties file that looks as follows:

```
jdbcClass=oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource
jdbcUrl=jdbc:oracle:thin:@stiddb01:1538:DSTD
username=*****
password=*****
```

I then exute a plain select * from a table and parse the results. All this works fine up to this point.

Then I created a small jsp/jstl tomcat application with this in my context.xml file for the datasource:

```
<Context>
    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
    <Resource
        name="jdbc/devdb"
        auth="Container"
        type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        maxActive="100"
        maxIdle="30"
        maxWait="10000"
        username="******"
        password="******"
        driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource"
        url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@stiddb01:1537:DSTD">
    </Resource>
</Context>
```

And this in my web.xml:

```
<resource-ref>
        <description>Dev Environment</description>
        <res-ref-name>jdbc/devdb</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

with the following jsp/jstl code in a jsp called query.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql" prefix="sql" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

<sql:query var="rs" dataSource="jdbc/devdb">
    select * from "ST_FINANCE"."STF_FINANCE_REQUEST"
</sql:query>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Results</h2>

    <c:forEach var="row" items="${rs.rows}">
        ${row.FINANCE_REQUEST_NO}<br />


    </c:forEach>
</body>
</html>
```

Then I get this error when I hit the page:

```
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

Why does my console app work perfectly but the webapp bails?
Only thing I could get it to work was making the table publicly accessable on the DB but we cant have that on our production servers...

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean by publicly accessible. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Is your Java console application supposed to be accessing the same database as the jsp/jstl tomcat application? Both the URL and the username/password appear to be different in the two applications.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though the two applications are accessing different databases as different users. Try granting select privileges on ST_FINANCE.STF_FINANCE_REQUEST to user dewet1_d in the database accessed by the jsp/jstl tomcat application.